# Flutter GetIt throws instance exception

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection

I am trying to register my services within my flutter application using `get_it` and one dependency needs to be initialized right at the start with an async call.
As I have read on the [official Get_It pub page](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it), this should not be a problem, as long as I am defining the dependsOn property for dependencies which depends on that initializable class.

In my example, `DeviceInfo` is the class which needs to be initialized and `Gateway` and `WorkingTimeRepository` both depend on this class. Both have defined their dependOn property.

```dart
void setup() {
  getIt.registerSingletonAsync<DeviceInfo>(() async => DeviceInfo.init());

  getIt.registerSingletonWithDependencies(
      () => Gateway(deviceInfo: getIt.get()),
      dependsOn: [DeviceInfo]);

  getIt.registerSingletonWithDependencies<WorkingTimeRepository>(
      () => WorkingTimeRepository(
          dio: new Dio(), httpHeader: new HttpHeader(), gateway: getIt.get()),
      dependsOn: [DeviceInfo, Gateway]);
}
```

Now when my application starts and my first Widget wants to access the WorkingTimeRepository, I instantly get an exception:

> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
> The following assertion was thrown building MainView:
> You tried to access an instance of WorkingTimeRepository that was not ready yet
> 'package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart':
> Failed assertion: line 322 pos 14: 'instanceFactory.isReady'

I cannot find my mistake I did, also I thought that when accessing the registered type, it resolves all dependent dependencies

Does someone know what is missing here?

Comment: Your DeviceInfo registration is async, and it probably is not yet registered at the time when your first widget wants to access it.

Comment: Yes it seems like, bit get_it provides an parameter named dependsOn where you can define the async dependencies which will be resolved first.. I also implemented it as described inside the docs without success

Answer (score 6):

When using async dependencies, you need to wait until all dependencies are created before starting your app. One way to do this is adding a TransitionBuilder to the MaterialApp with a FutureBuilder that listens to getIt.allReady().

Example:

```
return MaterialApp(
  builder: (context, widget) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: getIt.allReady(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return widget;
          } else {
            return Container(color: Colors.white);
          }
        });
  },
);
```

Comment: I wonder how this can be achieved in unit testing.

Comment: Well, I think one way to do that in unit testing is to call `getIt.allReady()` in `setUpAll` async body.

Comment: this works as charm